# Can I put other type of fork to a downhill frame? Is this a DH frame?

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, conversion, downhill

I've recently bought a 29er downhill frame and since I am new to MTB, I was wondering if I can put an other type of fork to this dh frame. Something like an enduro fork with 180mm travel?  [image]!
The following fotos are from other buyers that have already installed fork and other components. As you can see all of them have put "normal" forks and not double crown. So I wonder if the frame is a DH or something else...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xkmH.jpg)[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Unless you know exactly what you want and what you are doing, its likely cheaper to sell the bike and buy the one you want.

Comment: For one thing, you'd probably need some adapter trickery to run a conical axle in the DH frame's straight head tube. Seems to be possible, but it would likely not be as robust as an enduro fork in a conical headtube as it was designed for, and certainly not as robust as a double-crown fork which the frame was designed for. — 180mm enduro is _almost_ like a downhill fork anyway – a bit lighter, yes, but with the heavy DH frame that's not going to win you a cross-country race either... so unless you want to do jumps with barspins or so: _why_?

Comment: I see that this frame has a tapered headtube. So maybe this is not a downhill bike???

Comment: Check the geometry chart for your frame and the size. Just because it has a coill shock, does not mean it's DH, you can get coil shock for most size rear shocks. You wat to check the shot size, it will be something like, 190mm x 51mm, 200mm x 57mm ... etc all the way to 240mm 74mm and anything in between

Comment: BTW, it does not look like a DH frame to me from the pictures.If you put the link to where you bought it from, I can check the geometry and shock dimensions for you, they should also have a fork travel recomendation.

Comment: https://m.aliexpress.com/item/33037737225.html?spm=a2g0n.orderlist-amp.item.33037737225&aff_trace_key=522462f747ca48808dbaedec70c507a5-1590579242024-07559-UneMJZVf&aff_platform=msite&m_page_id=6449amp-xjF8RxImZLfXaauMlo3TzQ1591956867783&browser_id=50335d494d6841f6aae74bb3ebb3ed21&is_c=Y

Comment: This is the link for the shock.                        https://www.dnmshock.com/products.php?func=p_detail&p_id=22&pc_parent=12

Comment: It takes a 190 eye to eye length shock and a fork with axle to crown of 520 (according to their page). This is no where near DH. It's not even enduro level of decending.

Comment: As an example, the current Rockshox Pike 29er 120mm travel fork has an axle to crown of 531mm. So this frame was designed for a fork with less travel than that.

Comment: https://r2-bike.com/ROCK-SHOX-Suspension-Fork-29-REBA-RL-SA-120-mm-BOOST-Maxle-Stealth-OneLoc-tapered-black-2020   I searched the site and this fork has 526mm installation height, 51mm offset. Among others with the same length, it is cheaper and comes with Oneloc remote control. I searched for 41-44mm offset, so I could have bigger trail, but they come with 531mm installation height....

Answer (score 7):

Yes and no.

What really matters for handling of the bike is that the fork you use has the same axle to crown length and the same offset as the fork the bike should have.

The offset is the distance between the front axle and the steering axis

The axle to crown is the length between the center of the hub axle and the crown of the fork.

There's lots of people who've done it with no problems, but it also depends on your frame.

Why you shouldn't do it, is because if you get the wrong replacement fork, it will throw the geometry of the bike off and it won't ride as well as it should.

Unfortunately, this is also a bit of a personal and trial/error thing too. So someone might say "it worked for me no problem" and then you might try it and not like it.

In terms of handling, the head angle might become a little steeper and, in theory, having a lower travel fork might make cornering a little easier but it might also make the bike more unstable at higher speeds. Whether this is noticible in real life, I don't know.